# Dynamically populate data values into a R markdown equation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, dynamically-generated

Currently, I'm reading data in from a .txt as follows:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
Ex01_01_data = read.table("./data/Ex01.01.txt",header = T)
```
````

I then want to show my work as follows:

```
$$\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\frac{3.4+2.5+4.8+2.9+3.6+2.8+3.3+5.6+3.7+2.8+4.4+4.0+5.2+3.0+4.8}{15}=`r mean(Ex01_01_data$hour)`$$
```

As you can see I'm hard coding the values in but I'd like to know if there is a way to iterate through or auto populate the data into the equation. Is that something I can do in R?

Comment: Can you provide some example data along with expected output for the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you may use `cat` in the code chunk, and `results='asis'`

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
# Ex01_01_data <- read.table("./data/Ex01.01.txt", header=TRUE)

Ex01_01_data <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))

invisible(sapply(1:nrow(Ex01_01_data), function(m)
  cat("$\\bar{x}_", m, "=\\frac{1}{n}\\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=\\frac{",
      apply(Ex01_01_data[m, -4], 1, paste, collapse="+"), "}{15}={", 
      Ex01_01_data[m, 4], "}$\n\n")))
```
````

#### Gives:

[image]